# Perl JIRA POST error "headers must be presented as a hashref"

Tags: perl, post, jira, jira-rest-api

I am writing a Perl script to POST an attachment to JIRA using
[`REST::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client) to access the [API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/)
but I am getting an error.

```
use REST::Client;

use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Slurp;
use MIME::Base64;

my $user = 'user';
my $pass = 'pass';
my $url  = "http://******/rest/api/2/issue/BugID/attachments";

my $client = REST::Client->new();
$client->addHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic' . encode_base64( $user . ':' . $pass ) );
$client->addHeader( 'X-Atlassian-Token', 'no-check' );
$client->setHost( $url );

# my %header = ('Authorization' => 'Basic'. encode_base64($user . ':' . $pass),'X-Atlassian-Token' => 'no-check');

my $attachment = "C:\\Folder\\Test.txt";

$client->POST(
    $url,
    'Content_Type' => 'form-data',
    'Content'      => [ 'file' => [$attachment] ]
);

if ( $client->responseCode() eq '200' ) {
    print "Updated\n";
}

# print the result
print $client->responseContent() . "\n";
```

The error I get is

> REST::Client exception: headers must be presented as a hashref at C:\Users\a\filename.pl line 24.

As shown in the code, I have tried setting headers in different ways but I still get same error.

Please suggest if there is any other method.

I have tried using JIRA module but it gives error too.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client#POST-(-$url,-[$body_content,-%$headers]-)), the `POST` method:

> Takes an optional body content and hashref of custom request headers.

You need to put your headers in a hashref, e.g.:

```
$client->POST($url, $content, {
    foo => 'bar',
    baz => 'qux'
});
```

---

But...it looks like you're expecting REST::Client to use [HTTP::Request::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common#POST-$url) to construct a multipart/form-data request. Unfortunately, that's not the case, so you'll have to build the content by hand.

You *could* use HTTP::Request::Common directly like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use HTTP::Request::Common;
use REST::Client;

my $client = REST::Client->new;
my $url = 'http://www.example.com';

my $req = POST($url,
    Content_Type => 'form-data',
    Content      => [ file => [ 'foo.txt' ] ]
);

$client->POST($url, $req->content(), {
    $req->headers->flatten()
});
```

But this is a bit convoluted; I would recommend dropping REST::Client and using [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) instead. REST::Client is just a thin wrapper for LWP::UserAgent with a few convenience features, like prepending a default host to all requests. In this case, it's just getting in the way and I don't think the conveniences are worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> POST ( $url, [$body_content, %$headers] )

And you're doing:

```
$client->POST(
    $url,
    'Content_Type' => 'form-data',
    'Content'      => [ 'file' => [$attachment] ]
);
```

So - passing a list of scalars, with an arrayref at the end.

Perhaps you want something like:

```
$client->POST(
    $url,
    $attachment,
    { 'Content-Type' => 'form-data' }
);
```

Note the `{}` to construct an anonymous hash for the headers.

Although you probably want to open and include the 'attachment', because there's nothing in `REST::Client` about opening files and sending them automagically.

Comment: That module is essentially a wrapper around `LWP::UserAgent` and `URI`; I don't see anything to do with REST in there and the documentation is dreadful. `%$headers` is a strange way of specifying that the parameter should be a hash reference. I see that there's a method that hands back the `LWP::UserAgent` object it's using (or you can pass it your own in the constructor) so you can probably get to that object's file handling, but it's probably easier just to slurp the file and pass it in the call to `POST`, or perhaps use `LWP` directly.